# jquery .click function not working in c# mvc3 w/ Razor

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

For far too long I've been stumbling around trying to make a simple .click jquery method work in my c# site.  I just want it to call to a function in my controller, but I can't seem to get any button click to register.  The calls in it are very similar to a .change() function for another control that works just fine.

JQuery method in question:

```
$('#addUserButton').click(function () {
            var e = document.getElementById('searchDDL');
            var itemText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
            var url = encodeURI('@Url.Action("AddUser")' + "?User=" + itemText);
        });
```

HTML of button that is intended to trigger the above function:

```
<button id="addUserButton" type="button" value="addUser">&gt;</button>
```

Some things I've researched and tried already:

- Changing from a .click() method to a .live("click", etc) method made no difference.
- I saw that setting the button type="submit" would be a problem, so I changed it to "button."
- I made sure to include it in document.ready() - I was already doing this before researching other problems.

I have created a jsfiddle for the problem [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MQLB4/). I had to remove a lot of sensitive information so the page is not fully fleshed out.  It is for an internal application and only has to work with IE.

**EDIT:**  Below I am adding the function I am trying to call in my controller; other posters have verified that the jquery is working as expected, so I'm inclined to believe it is something to do with my c#.

```
public ActionResult AddUser(string User)
    {
        //numUsers = App.NumberUsers + 1;
        selectedUsers.Add(User);
        return RedirectToAction("ApplicationForm");
    }
```

Comment: The fiddle works for me when I include jQuery.

Comment: Your jsfiddle contains @Url.Action() references in the JavaScript. Can you at least confirm that these are populated with proper URLs when you're running this in your live environment?

Comment: @AdrianWragg - I added alerts and verified that, yes, the @Url.Action() references are populated with URLs. Relative URLs, but valid URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try debugging your function or even putting alerts in it to flesh out whats happening.

```
$('#addUserButton').click(function () {
alert("FUNCTION IS GETTING CALLED ON CLICK EVENT");
            var e = document.getElementById('searchDDL');
alert(e);
            var itemText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
alert(itemText);
            var url = encodeURI('@Url.Action("AddUser")' + "?User=" + itemText);
alert(url);
        });
```

Doesn't look like your function makes an AJAX request after getting the URL.

Comment: I did add alerts to debug and verified that the function is getting called and accessed as expected. As you pointed out, I never made a call with the url; I added `$("contentDiv").load(url);` like in my other function. Unfortunately it still isn't firing off the function. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @rgreasons - $("#contentDiv").load(url); you need a # before your ID

Comment: ^sure enough.  I would have swore I put one in there since it was copy and paste.  ugh. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's not something silly like the extra closing `>` bracket on this?

```
<button id="addUserButton" type="button" value="addUser">></button>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update that after another commenter mentioned the issue, but it appears he deleted his comment.  But no, it wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQLB4/), **it seems you're not including the `jQuery`.**

***Which is at the top-left corner of JSFiddle.***

I've [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MQLB4/4/) working fine.  Remember you're including `jQuery`, so try to make use of its feature and leave Javascript.